# Not shown x-axis labels in matplotlib subplots from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, subplot

I try to print out subplots. Sadly just the last of those plots has x axis labels / dates shown. How can I show the date below each graph.

It looks like this, but I wan't x axis for all graphs

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

axes = dfDiscoverNerPivot.plot.line(x="date",subplots=True, legend=True, fontsize=8, grid=False, figsize=(10,25), linewidth=3)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

for ax in axes.flatten():
    ax.axhline(5000, color='k', linestyle='--')
    ax.legend(loc='upper center')

plt.show()
```

I'm using google colab and pandas.

Comment: In pure matplotlib, this occurs when using the option `sharex` with the `plt.subplots` function. You seem to be using an unidentified object (`dfDiscoverNerPivot`) with its own matplotlob helper functions. See if that object makes use of the `sharex` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `subplots=True` and all subplots are sharing the same x-axis. Passing in `sharex=False` in the `plot.line` method should do the trick.

You can pass in keyword arguments into `DataFrame.plot.line` which are passed onto `DataFrame.plot`. You can check them out in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot).